# How to update multiple fields in a row without knowing which ones are to be updated in advance

Tags: php, sql, multiple-columns

I'm working on an 'updateProfile' webservice whereby a user can update one or more of a number of fields and I'm stumped as to how to form the Query. I was thinking I could have multiple if isset conditions and contenate onto the query as needed. However, I will run into the issue of not knowing which ones are posted ahead of time and thus not knowing whether to include ANDs or commas etc. Here is my starting point:

```
$UpdateTradesman_Query= "UPDATE Tradesmen SET ";
            if(isset($_REQUEST['FName'])){
                $FName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FName']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "FName ='".$FName."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['SName'])){
                $SName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SName']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "SName ='".$SName."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['Email'])){
                $Email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "Email ='".$Email."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['HomePhone'])){
                $HomePhone=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['HomePhone']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "HomePhone ='".$HomePhone."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['Mobile'])){
                $Mobile=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mobile']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "Mobile ='".$Mobile."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['Trade'])){
                $Trade=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Trade']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "Trade ='".$Trade."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['Address'])){
                $Address=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "Address ='".$Address."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['County'])){
                $County=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['County']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "County ='".$County."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['PostCode'])){
                $PostCode=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PostCode']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "PostCode ='".$PostCode."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['Photo'])){
                $Photo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Photoe']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "Photo ='".$Photo."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['Profile'])){
                $Profile=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Profile']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "Profile ='".$Profile."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['Qualification'])){
                $Qualification=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Qualification']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "Qualification ='".$Qualification."'";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['AvailabilityTimes'])){
                $AvailabilityTimes=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AvailabilityTimes']);
                $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "AvailabilityTimes ='".$AvailabilityTimes."'";
            }   

            $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "WHERE TradesmanID=".$TradesmanID;
            echo $UpdateTradesman_Query;
            if (mysql_query($UpdateTradesman_Query)){
                $status= 'OK';
                $message= 'null';
                $Update= "OK";
            }
            else{

                $status= 'Not OK';
                $message= 'Error: Query Unsuccessful.'. mysql_error();
                $Update= "Not OK";
            }
```

I also have to take into consideration that if a user chooses to update either a username or an email, I will haveto ensure that a) the email is not already associated with another account(already in database) or b) the username is not already taken. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with what you currently have, you could add a flag and add commas like:

```
$addcomma=false;

$UpdateTradesman_Query= "UPDATE Tradesmen SET ";
        if(isset($_REQUEST['FName'])){
            $FName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FName']);
            $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "FName ='".$FName."'";
            $addcomma= true;
        }
        if(isset($_REQUEST['SName'])){
            $SName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SName']);
            if($addcomma) $UpdateTradesman_Query.= ",";
            $UpdateTradesman_Query.= "SName ='".$SName."'";
            $addcomma= true;
        }
..etc..
```